# How can I make a Java method generic?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I am currently working on a project where I have to make some method generic (to make the code more readable).

The projects has two classes: `Box` and `MyList`.
The constructor for 'Box' accepts to generic parameters; the constructor for 'MyList' only one.

```
public class Box<A, B> {}
```

That is the class for the box.

```
public class MyList<T> {}
```

And thats the class for MyList.

In the class 'Box' I have a method that looks like this:

```
public static MyList enclose (Box <MyList <Integer, String>> t) {
// Here comes some code that is not important right now.
}
```

What I want now, is to make this method generic so that it not only takes in parameters like a `Box`. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: is searching google really that hard? -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a meaningful way unless you have a common interface for all classes you want to support here.

Comment: or are you asking how to prevent the hard-coded "<Integer, String>" ?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a member variable that takes a parameter of type Object rather than Box<a, b>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you want to do, and the number of generic parameters do not match your classes but maybe this does the work?

```
public <T> static MyList<T> enclose (Box <MyList <T>, String> t) {
// Here comes some code that is not important right now.
}
```

Or if you want to avoid talking about MyList, maybe this:

```
public <T> static T enclose (Box <T, String> t) {
// Here comes some code that is not important right now.
}
```

The second version has the type of the first generic parameter of the `Box` object as its return type...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static <T> MyList<T> enclose(T t) {
    return new MyList<T>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyList<Box<String, String>> res = enclose(new Box<String, String>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T, S> MyList<T> enclose(Box <MyList<T>, S> box) {}
```

Java does not have [higher kinded types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29), so the above is as generic as java will allow.

Alternatively, without the requirement of having `MyList<T>`

```
public static <T, S> T enclose(Box <T, S> box) {}
```

Hopefully these 2 examples give you a rough idea of how to declare generics in your specific case.